# Dropdown postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I´ve made a dropmenu but when I want to post to a specific page when there is a post back. Nothing happens? I'm working with the laravel framework. This is my code:

```
@extends('master')
@section('title', 'Create a new ticket')

@section('content')

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var xhr;
    });
    $("#test").change(function(e) {

    csrf = $("#token").attr('content')
    option = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
          url: '/receiveuserinformation',
          type: 'POST',
          data: { option_id: option },
          beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrf);},
          success: function(result) {
              $("#kilometersprive").val(result);
          }
      });
  });
</script>


 <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="content" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Standaard route</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <select class="form-control input-sm" name="test" id="test">
                                @foreach($standaardroute as $route)
                                    <option value="{!! $route->id !!}">{!! $route->van !!} - {!! $route->naar !!}</option>
                                @endforeach
                                </select>               
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

In my console are now errors?

EDIT

This is my routes file

```
Route::post('/receiveuserinformation','route@createroute');
```

This is my route@createroute

```
 public function createroute(Request $request)
    {
        $karakterrit = karakterrit::all();
        $foundroute = standaardroute::whereId($request->all())->firstorFail();
        $standaardroute = standaardroute::all();

        return view('ritten.create',compact('karakterrit',$karakterrit))->with('foundroute',$foundroute)->with('standaardroute',$standaardroute);
    }
```

Comment: You need to add more information. We need to see your routes.php and the respective controllers. It would also be helpful to add the response that are being sent back from the ajax call. You can see this in the network tab of the developer tools in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that

```
url: '/receiveuserinformation',
```

is pointing to the right URL? Make sure of it by using the [URLs Helpers on Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#urls)

Maybe you should use something like

```
url: {{ url("receiveuserinformation") }}
```

to be sure to point **always** to the right url.

Comment: Do you have a controller that is named *route*? This is the first time I see something like this. I suggest you to follow naming convention for classes and objects in order to write a better code :) Let me know about the *route* controller...

Comment: Oke, my developer tools are telling me The requested URL /receiveuserinformation was not found on this server....... but that's strange because it's in my routes file?

Comment: If you note it, you're specifying the route with an optional parameter, than in the method you're using it anyway... pay attention to your code!

Comment: Are you sure that *$request->all()* is returning just the id? Usually it returns an array... Try with *$request->get('id');* maybe.

Comment: I didn't had public in front now it finds the postback. But now it is telling me this: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Comment: Add to your post data a *_token* field and generate the token with csrf_token() helper. Details at: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-csrf-token

Otherwise, you can comment the middleware from app/Http/Kernel.php to remove it from the stack, but it's not safe.

Comment: Could you tell me how to add this to my request? Do I have to put                         {!! csrf_field() !!} in my jquery code?

Comment: I think that *{{ csrf_token() }}* is enough. :)

Something like data{ _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", ... other data here... }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are syntax errors in your code. You need to post to the route manually and see what errors you get. Or if you are using a browser like Chrome you can see the response that the ajax call is getting back with the Developer Tools.

```
// Remove the optional id parameter as you don't need it if you are POSTing it.
Route::post('/receiveuserinformation','route@createroute');

// Remove $id as you don't need it, and replace it with the request
public function createroute(Request $request)
{
    // Get the id from the POST data
    $id = $request->input('option_id');

    $karakterrit = karakterrit::all();

    // You should really catch this exception if there isn't a matching id
    $foundroute = standaardroute::whereId($id)->firstorFail();

    $standaardroute = standaardroute::all();

    return view('ritten.create', compact('karakterrit', 'foundroute', 'standaardroute'));
}
```